# rename multiple files with delimiters

Tags: command-line, sed, rename, awk

How could I rename multiple files like,

```
IonXpress_049.T11014.R_2014_11_13_11_26_35_user_PR2-41-Pooling0026_3140_13112014.bam
IonXpress_050.T11114.R_2014_11_13_11_26_35_user_PR2-41-Pooling0026_3140_13112014.bam
```

To,

```
T11014.bam 
T11114.bam
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to rename from command line. Here is a one liner. Go to the directory where the `.bam` files are located and try this,

```bsh
for i in *.bam; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | awk -F"." '{print $2}').bam"; done
```

#### How it works:

- Using a for loop and shell glob trapping the desired files,

```
    for i in *.bam
    do
        mv source destination
    done
```

- Next extract the part that you want to keep i.e. the second field of the string separated by `.` using `awk` as,

```
    $ echo IonXpress_049.T11014.R_2014_11_13_11_26_35_user_PR2-41-Pooling0026_3140_13112014.bam | awk -F"." '{print $2}'
    $ T11014
```

One can use custom field separator using `-F` option. See `man awk` for more.

Answer (score 8):

```
rename 's/.*?\.([^.]+).*/$1.bam/' *.bam -vn
```

Remove the `-vn` when you can see it does what you want. Here's my test harness:

```
$ touch 34234234kh.TESTING00{1..3}.234978623478y234.bam
$ rename 's/.*?\.([^.]+).*/$1.bam/' *.bam -vn
34234234kh.TESTING001.234978623478y234.bam renamed as TESTING001.bam
34234234kh.TESTING002.234978623478y234.bam renamed as TESTING002.bam
34234234kh.TESTING003.234978623478y234.bam renamed as TESTING003.bam
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use wonderful `krename` program:

```
sudo apt-get install krename
```

In this program you have a *preview* of result, and can, in particular, use just certain range of file-name mask:

[image]

The mask is at ➀. See the original file names at ➁ and to-be names at ➂. If it seems fine you can press finish: ➃ — only after this the files will actually be renamed.

Answer (score 3):

Use find command to finding all `*.bam` files and by while loop read each files one by one and finally with `mv` command rename them into your desired names.

```
find /path/to/maindir -type f -name "*.bam" -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r file
do
    echo mv -v "$file" /path/to/maindir/"$(awk -F'.' '{print $2".bam"}'<<< "$file")";
done
```

Result:

```
mv -v /home/USER/maindir/IonXpress_049.T11014.R_2014_11_13_11_26_35_user_PR2-41-Pooling0026_3140_13112014.bam /home/USER/maindir/T11014.bam
mv -v /home/USER/maindir/IonXpress_050.T11114.R_2014_11_13_11_26_35_user_PR2-41-Pooling0026_3140_13112014.bam /home/USER/maindir/T11114.bam
```

If you checked the result remove the `echo` command to real rename.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that

- the desired name- "body" is always after the first dot
- the `.bam` extension is always present
- the directory is "flat" and has no sub directories

This python solution should do the job. The number of sections may vary, it would still work:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import shutil
import sys

directory = sys.argv[1]

for item in os.listdir(directory):
    if not item.startswith("."):
        edit = item.split("."); newname = (".").join([edit[1], edit[-1]])
        if len(edit) > 2:
            shutil.move(directory+"/"+item, directory+"/"+newname)
```

Copy it into an empty file, make it executable (to run it without the `python3` prefix) and run it by the command:

```
</path/to/script> <directory_with_files>
```

So that:

```
monkey.banana.peanut.bam
```

becomes

```
banana.bam
```

and

```
monkey.apple.peaunt.another_string.and_alot_more.bam
```

becomes

```
apple.bam
```

while

```
something.bam
```

is left alone.

Answer (score 1):

Another python solution through `re` module.

`script.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import re
import os
import shutil

directory = sys.argv[1]
for item in os.listdir(directory):
    if '.' in item:
        newname = re.sub(r'^[^.]+\.([^.]*).+(\.bam)', r'\1\2', item)
        shutil.move(directory+"/"+item, directory+"/"+newname)
```

**How to run?**

```
python3 script.py /path/to/the/directory/where/the/files/you/want/to/rename/are/stored
```

Answer (score 0):

While all these answers are good I want to show you a method that does not involve programming (and can be much faster when you have already Sublime Text installed)

- Install Sublime Text (http://www.sublimetext.com/) Install the
- Sublime Package Control (https://packagecontrol.io/installation)
- Install the Package FileBrowser (`ctrl+shif+p` > Install Package > FileBrowser http://github.com/aziz/SublimeFileBrowser)
- Configure the FileBrowser keyboard shortcut (`ctrl+shift+p` > Key Bindings User) e.g.

  `{
    "keys": ["f1"],
    "command": "dired",
    "args": { "immediate": true }
  }`
- start the FileBrowser (`F1`)
- multiselect your files (select common pattern > `ctrl+d`)
- go into rename mode (`shift+R`)
- edit like common text editor (e.g. `ctrl+right` to jump between words)
- apply rename with `Enter`